# Solr escape characters in field name

Tags: solr

How can i escape special character in field name??

http://localhost:8983/solr/col/select?boost=if(exists(img-image_string),5,1)&debugQuery=on

```
gives me error error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"undefined field: \"img\"",
    "code":400}}
```

Comment: You should not use character other than alphanumeric and underscore

Answer (score 1):

Solr / Lucene uses `\` as its escape character, but you should really try to avoid using characters with special meaning in field names.

Comment: Except that Tika and SolrCell quite frequently add fields with :,-, or spaces to documents so it's not always in your control to prevent it.

Comment: Sure, but if possible - try to avoid it. Secondly, use the `lowernames` parameter with Solr Cell to at least normalize parts of field names (not sure if you'll get `:` converted to `_`, but `-` should be handled at least).